# Python Kivy: active property of checkbox gets the wrong value from ini file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a checkbox with these properties in a .kv file:

```
CheckBox:
    active: root.audio_word_count_enabled
    on_press: root.audio_word_count(self)
```

and inside of my actual code I have this

```
config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
audio_word_count_enabled = BooleanProperty(config['SAVES']['audio_word_count'])

def audio_word_count(self, checkbox):
    if checkbox.state == 'down':
        self.config.set('SAVES', 'audio_word_count', 'True')
        with open('config.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            self.config.write(configfile)
            configfile.flush()
            configfile.close()
        self.audio_word_count_enabled = self.config['SAVES']['audio_word_count']
        print(self.config['SAVES']['audio_word_count'])

    else:
        self.config.set('SAVES', 'audio_word_count', 'False')
        with open('config.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            self.config.write(configfile)
            configfile.flush()
            configfile.close()
        self.audio_word_count_enabled = self.config['SAVES']['audio_word_count']
        print(self.config['SAVES']['audio_word_count'])
```

The most important part is the audio_word_count_enabled which comes from my ini file. When I start my app the checkbox is automatically active despite what is inside of the ini file. I tried printing the audio_word_count_enabled and it is getting the correct values(True or False).
Any suggestions?

Comment: A `BooleanProperty` (or any `Property`) must be defined within a class (normally a `Widget`). I don't see that in your posted code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson that is the whole class but I forgot to copy the class name. If I say audio_word_count_enabled = BooleanProperty(False)
which is exactly the same as 
audio_word_count_enabled = BooleanProperty(config['SAVES']['audio_word_count'])
The first one works correctly but the second one doesnt, even though they both get the value: False

Comment: Without seeing complete code, there is no way to determine what is happening. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the values in `config.ini` are string values and `BooleanProperty()` expects a `boolean` value. So you just need to replace:

```
 audio_word_count_enabled = BooleanProperty(config['SAVES']['audio_word_count'])
```

with:

```
audio_word_count_enabled = BooleanProperty(config.getboolean('SAVES', 'audio_word_count'))
```

which converts the value from `config` into a `Boolean`.